# Matlab code for logistic map bifurcation

Tags: matlab, bifurcation

Take the logistic map

$$x(i+1) = f(xi), f(x) = rx(1 − x)$$

Find numerically the $r$ values for the first two bifurcations.

I know I have to set $f(x)=0$, solve for $x$, and then use the $x$ values to find $r$. So, in Matlab I did

```
syms x r;
solve(r*x*(1-x)==0,r);
```

From this I've found that $r = 0$ and $r = 1$. Is this correct? If not, what did I do wrong here? Or, just help me find the bifurcation values here.

Answer (score 1):

The bifurcations occur for the Logistic map at the points when the period doubles.

For instance, suppose that $b$ is the first bifurcation point. Then, for $b<r$ the Logistic map will have a fixed point (i.e. period-1 point) and for $b>r$ it will have period-2 points. You need to find the particular value for $b$ that makes this true.

Similarly, the second bifurcation point occurs in the change from period-2 to period-4 points.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. But, how do I find such a value for b?

Comment: A non-optimal method is to generate a sequence and see if it is period 1 or 2. If it is period 1, you know that you need to choose $r$ higher. If it is period 2, $r$ needs to be chosen smaller. This will eventually give you a bracket for the value, at which point bisecting could be used.